# React Native navigating between Nested StackNavigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

I have the three navigators below, I am navigating to the DashBoard Screen after the login is completed but I have an issue when I want to logout from the DashBoard Screen, **this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')** is working fine but I want to clear the stack when signout button is pressed.

```
const DashBoardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      DashBoard: DashBoard,
      Second:Second,
      Third:Third
    })


const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  DashBoardStackNavigator,
  Account,
  Report,
  Members
}})

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Login: Login,
  BottomTabNavigator: BottomTabNavigator

})


export default createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator)
```

I tried the following with no luck

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

> Error: there is no route defined for key Login, Must Be one of
>   DashBoard

Comment: Try to add 'key: null' to your StackActions.reset. See if it works

Comment: Its not working

Comment: try this, `this.props.navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())`
This will pop all screens except first one.

Comment: When I navigated to the Dashboard Screen I already reset the stack and DashBoard is the first screen Because I don't want the user to navigate back to login Screen after sign in.

Comment: same issue, did you find solution? @basilsatti

Comment: @AdirZoari yeah, see Ahmed imam’s answer below

Comment: @basilsatti I did, but show me the same error. can you check on my issue the example? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755122/react-navigation-3-reset-in-nested-stack

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
 const navigateAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            key: null,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })]
        })
        this.props.navigation.dispatch(navigateAction)
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use a `SwitchNavigator`, as suggested by the following official documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

In your case, just replace the last StackNavigator with a SwitchNavigator:

```
const DashBoardStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
      DashBoard: DashBoard,
      Second:Second,
      Third:Third
    })


const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  DashBoardStackNavigator,
  Account,
  Report,
  Members
}})

const AppStackNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
  Login: Login,
  BottomTabNavigator: BottomTabNavigator

})


export default createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator)
```

Then just navigate to the Login:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('Login')
```

It will automatically reset the stack when you switch between the bottomTabNavigator stack and the login stack, blocking all back actions between the two.

Comment: With react-navigation v5, there is a better, simpler solution than the switch navigator: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-4.x/#switch-navigator
I'm not even sure the switch navigator still exists in v5.