# react-navigation 3 reset in nested stack

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-navigation

Im try to understand how to reset in nested stack
this my code

```
    const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        Welcome,
        Login,
        Register,
        ConfirmationCode,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'Welcome',
        headerMode: 'none',
        lazy: true,
        transitionConfig,
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        },
      }
    )

    const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
      {
        TabStack,
        SearchResult,
        BusinessDetail,
        BusinessMap,
        MakeAppointment,
        TermsAndConditions
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'TabStack',
        headerMode: 'none',
        lazy: true,
        transitionConfig,
        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        },
      }
    )

    let MainStack = createSwitchNavigator(
      {
        AuthLoading,
        Auth: AuthStack,
        App: AppStack,
      },
      {
        initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
        headerMode: 'none',
        lazy: true,

        defaultNavigationOptions: {
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        },
      }
    )
```

TabStack

```
    import React from 'react';

    import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
    import {
        Search,
        MyFavourites,
        MyAppointments,
        UserProfile
    } from '../screens'
    import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Feather';
    import Colors from '../utils/Colors'
    let TabStack = createBottomTabNavigator(
      {
        Search,
         MyFavourites,
         MyAppointments,
         UserProfile,
      },
        initialRouteName: 'ScreenTab1',
        tabBarOptions: {
          activeTintColor: Colors.pink,
          inactiveTintColor: Colors.black,
          showLabel: false,
          style: {
            backgroundColor: 'white'
          }
        },
      }
    )
    export default createAppContainer(TabStack);
```

I want to understand how to make reset for example:

```
    reset from UserProfile to TabStack (in AppStack) to AuthStack
```

I tried to do from it this way

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AuthStack' })],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

or this way

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
        index: 0,
        key: null,
        actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'AuthStack' })],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

but i got the error

> there is no route defined for AuthStack

I checked in issues in stackoverflow but the answers there not works for me,always show me the same error I wrote above.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native navigating between Nested StackNavigator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54704752/react-native-navigating-between-nested-stacknavigator)

Comment: @JaydeepGalani I tried this solution, not working, it show the same error.

Comment: Check your route name, it should be `Auth` instead of `AuthStack` as your declaration :) And reset with key null will work cause it'll reset the root nav.

Comment: I did as you can see here, same error https://pastebin.com/hvJ7Mp7b

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `resetAction` is unsuccessful because you are dispatching it on `TabStack` (because you are calling `this.props.navigation.dispatch` on `UserProfile`, if I get you correctly). You need to dispatch the `resetAction` to your `MainStack` instead. [This thread here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335) suggested some ways that you can achieve this. And also, here is my preferred solution, because i don't have to pass props around navigators or calls multiple nested actions with this.

1. Create a `navigationService.js` with the following contents (to keep your top level navigator as a reference)

```js
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigateMainNavigator(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    NavigationActions.navigate({
      routeName,
      params,
    }),
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  setTopLevelNavigator,
  navigateMainNavigator,
};
```

2. On your `App.js` or any other file you render your `MainStack`, do this to set the reference

```js
import NavigationService from './navigationService';

...

render() {
  return (

    ...
    <MainStack
      ref={navigatorRef => {
        NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
      }}
    />
    ...

  )
}
```

3. And wherever when you want to reset to your `AuthStack` (or any other stack in your `MainStack`), just import `NavigationService` and call

```js
NavigationService.navigateAndReset('Auth', {...yourParamsIfAny});
// 'Auth' because you named it that way in your 'MainStack'
```

===========================================================================

## Edited

Previous solution, in `navigationService.js`, is for `StackNavigator` as the `MainStack`

```js
function navigateAndReset(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName,
          params,
        }),
      ],
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: hey wicky, sounds like great way to do that! Im using with mobx so I did it in my store, I copy part of my code here, you can see https://pastebin.com/KtnMAXYy  I also printed the ref to see what's it include and see all his properties. but I still got same error.. maybe I miss something..

Comment: Hey Adir, I am not familiar with mobx. But try doing a `conosle.log(this.main_navigation_ref)` on your `resetMainStack` function, and check if you're on the correct navigator. Try looking for the navigator's routes, [this image](https://imgur.com/a/GTXUDYg) might help

Comment: you can see the console.log here https://imgur.com/a/tWhfMHA  it show me the mainStack

Comment: Ahh, I just realise your `MainStack` is actually a `SwitchNavigator`. In that case, you dont need the `StackActions.reset` action. Just the `NavigationActions.navigate` will do. I have updated my answer above

Comment: exactly what I need!!!!  what the difference  between stack actions.reset to NavigationActions?

Comment: Gald it helps. `StackActions.reset` (with `index: 0`) is to reset your `StackNavigator`'s stack, so that when you push a new screen using `NavigationActions.navigate` to it, the new screen will be the first screen on the `StackNavigator`. Without `StackActions.reset`, it will push the new screen on top of the stack, which you can still go back to the previous screen using the `back button` or `swipe left`. Since your `MainStack` is a `SwitchNavigator` but not a `StackNavigator`, you dont need to reset the stack.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189062/discussion-between-adir-zoari-and-wicky).

Answer (score 1):

Try by setting it to `AppStack`, because anyhow it is going to redirect to `GeneralStack` as you have it as `initialRouteName` inside `AppStack`

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      key: null,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'App' })],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

Comment: What do u mean? I want to reset from userProfile of tabstack to screenA of authstack.. how to do that?

Comment: But in question you are trying to reset it to `GeneratStack` instead of `AuthStack`

Comment: I try to do some resets, the last one i ask you is to implement logout.. any idea?

Comment: In that case you can directly reset it to `Auth`

Comment: I tried to reset from UserProfile of tabStack to screenA of AuthStack with this code https://pastebin.com/hvJ7Mp7b . I get the same error "error:error:there is no route defined for key Auth. must be one of 'TabStack,...."

Comment: @ I edit my post with real names to make it easier understand. check again – Adir Zoari 9 mins ago    Delete

Comment: @RaviRupareliya, In my case MainNav is StackNav, Also I have a switchNav within it, then a StackNav within the switchNav. I want to rest the inner stackNav in some situations but it fails. it seems the outer stack going to reset and because I'm passing one of the inner StackNav routeName it can not find that on outer stackNav. I have a NavigationService util file just like you post in your answer. have you any idea how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following, to reset to `authStack`,

create a reset actions as following,

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "AuthStack" })],
  key: null
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
```

and also add the AuthStack into appStack, or the stack from which you are calling the above code.

For example if your calling this from your appstack, add the following line as a route within your app stack

```
  const AppStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    TabStack,
    SearchResult,
    BusinessDetail,
    BusinessMap,
    MakeAppointment,
    TermsAndConditions,
    AuthStack <---Insert THIS
  },
```

This works for me when using to signout.

Comment: I know this kind of way but I dont think this right way.. becauae if i want to reset in more complex stacks so i need always declare it in same level of stack...