# React Native Switch Navigator: goBack() not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have a switch navigator:

```
export default createSwitchNavigator({
  AuthLoading: AuthLoadingScreen,
  EditProfile: EditProfileScreen,
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Register: RegisterScreen,
  ForgotPassword: ForgotPasswordScreen,
  Main: MainTabNavigator,
  MainLoading: MainLoadingScreen,
  TripReport: TripReportScreen,
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading',
});
```

When I am on 'Main', a tab navigator, I have a button that navigates me to the 'TripReport' screen:

`onPress={() => navigation.navigate('TripReport', {tripReport: tripReport})}`

When on the TripReportScreen, I added an event listener for the Android back button to return to the 'Main', but also to the specific Tab:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    // Add event listener for the Android back button.
    BackHandler.addEventListener("hardwareBackPress", () => {
      this.props.navigation.goBack(null);
      return true
    })
  }
```

The goBack function isn't working. The only way I've gotten it to work is

`navigation.navigate('Main)`

but this reloads 'Main' instead of going back to the state the screen had.

Answer (score 4):

Yup, This is correct behaviour.
If I had to quote [reactnavigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-prop.html#goback-close-the-active-screen-and-move-back)

*Optionally provide a key, which specifies the route to go back from. By default, goBack will close the route that it is called from. If the goal is to go back anywhere, without specifying what is getting closed, call .goBack(null); Note that the null parameter is useful in the case of nested StackNavigators to go back on a parent navigator when the child navigator already has only one item in the stack.*

This would work only with `StackNavigators`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are there any options for the Switch Navigator?

Comment: You might wanna use the `backBehavior` and set to `initialRoute`.
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/switch-navigator.html

Answer (score 0):

Thats because when you call `this.props.navigation.goBack` on `Main`, `this.props.navigation` actually refers to your `MainTabNavigator`. Thats why your back action did not work.

You need to reach the correct `SwitchNavigator` in order to dispatch a `back` action to your `SwitchNavigator`, check out a few ways [suggested on this thread](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335).

Or, you can also create a reference to your `switchNavigator`, checkout this answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54878858/2963461