# Reset main StackNavigator when user logout?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm building a react native app there is login logout of user features.

I want to reset my main `StackNavigator` when user logout from system and move on login screen.

I'm getting issue when I reset my main `StackNavigator` from drawer menu.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
const OrderStack = createStackNavigator({
    Orders: {
        screen: Orders,
    },
    OrderDetails: {
        screen: OrderDetails,
    },
    DeliveryStatus: {
        screen: DeliveryStatus,
    },
    DeliveryInstructions: {
        screen: DeliveryInstructions,
    },
    ProductDetails: {
        screen: ProductDetails,
    },
});

const DrawerNavigations = createDrawerNavigator({
    Home: OrderStack,
    Location: {
        screen: createStackNavigator({
            Location: {
                screen: Location,
            },
        }),
    }
});
const RootStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        Login: {
            screen: Login,
        },
        Home: {
            screen: DrawerNavigations,
        }
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Login',
        headerMode: 'none',
        navigationOptions: {
            headerVisible: false,
        }
    },
);


const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack);

export default class Main extends Component{
    render() {
        return (
            <AppNavigator
                ref={navigatorRef => {
                    NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
                }}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

My `logout` button code:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
    index: 0,
    actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })],
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction)
```

`navigationService.js`

```
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigateAndReset(routeName){
    _navigator.dispatch(
        StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            actions: [
                NavigationActions.navigate({
                    routeName,
                }),
            ],
        })
    );
}

export default {
    setTopLevelNavigator,
    navigateAndReset,
};
```

Comment: Change this line `actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Home' })],` to **`actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Login' })],`** on logout press

Comment: whats the Issue you get?

Comment: key login not found

only allow Orders: {
        screen: Orders,
    },
    OrderDetails: {
        screen: OrderDetails,
    },
    DeliveryStatus: {
        screen: DeliveryStatus,
    },
    DeliveryInstructions: {
        screen: DeliveryInstructions,
    },
    ProductDetails: {
        screen: ProductDetails,
    },

Comment: @SiSa it's like a navigate to left to right and when i press back it will back

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen see my updated answers

Comment: @HardikVirani did you check the react-navigation documentation on authentication flow https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/auth-flow.html

Comment: @NaveedSheriffdeen yes, but it not help me as i have parent child flow in navigation

Comment: @HardikVirani add the `Login` route into your `OrderStack` then the error you get will be removed And try this `const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: "Login" })],
  key: null
});
this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
`

Comment: Hey @HardikVirani, i answered another question that is very similar to you question. Check it out, let me know if it helps. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54755122/react-navigation-3-reset-in-nested-stack/54878858#54878858

Comment: @wicky no, it's not working for me at all

Comment: Ahh..which solution did you follow?

Comment: i gave an answer according to your case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `resetAction` is unsuccessful because you are dispatching the action onto `OrderStack`. You need to dispatch the `resetAction` to your `RootStack` instead. [This thread here](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/335) suggested some interesting ways that you can achieve this, have a read.

And also, here is my preferred solution. Because with this, i don't have to pass props around navigators or calls multiple nested actions.

1. Create a `navigationService.js` with the following contents (to keep your top level navigator as a reference)

```js
import { NavigationActions, StackActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
  _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigateAndReset(routeName, params) {
  _navigator.dispatch(
    StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [
        NavigationActions.navigate({
          routeName,
          params,
        }),
      ],
    })
  );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
  setTopLevelNavigator,
  navigateAndReset,
};
```

2. On your `App.js` or any other file you render your `AppNavigator`(or `RootStack`), import `NavigationService` and set a reference to your `AppNavigator`

```js
import NavigationService from './navigationService';

...

render() {
  return (

    ...
    <AppNavigator
      ref={navigatorRef => {
        NavigationService.setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef);
      }}
    />
    ...

  )
}
```

3. And wherever when you want to reset to your `Login` page, just import `NavigationService` and call

```js
NavigationService.navigateAndReset('Login', {...yourParamsIfAny});
```

Comment: would you mind sharing what have you changed and the error you get?

Comment: You should call `NavigationService.navigateAndReset('Login');` on your logout button, can you try this and let me know if it works?

Comment: Ok, try to do a `console.log(_navigator)` ontop of the `navigateAndReset` function to check if you are on the correct navigator. If its correct, you should be able to see `Login` and `Home` in `routes`. Checkout [this image](https://imgur.com/a/GTXUDYg)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189599/discussion-between-hardik-virani-and-wicky).